# How to adjust asp placeholder size according to content

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, placeholder

I have a placeHolder which holds few elements, one of them is **tgl** div, by clicking on **OpenTime** button the tgl div is visible or hidden.
My problem is that the placeHolder **OpenTime** size is static, when tgl visibility is hidden, the placeHolder takes unnecessary space.
 Is it possible to change the placeHolder size according to content ?
    I must use placeHolder.

//HTML

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="OpenTime" >     
      <input type="button" id="open" onclick="toggleDiv()" value="Edit Time" style="width:130px"/>
    <div id="tgl" style="visibility:hidden;overflow:hidden;min-height:1px">             
        <div id="majinDiv" style="width: 600px"; ></div>
    </div><br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `display: none;` css instead of `visibility:hidden;`

`display: block;` to show the element back.

visibility controls the visibility but the space is still preserved. But display:none clears the space as if the element was not even there.